# Include specific packages in spring boot application build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven-2, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Is there a way to include specific packages during a spring boot application build? I have used spring-boot-maven plugin.
 
I understand it's not very customary to have classes in the same project which we don't want in the build, but I want to check if this is possible at all?
Even if a spring-boot executable jar can be built using any other way (i.e. by not using the spring-boot-maven plugin) I'd be delighted to know.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @EssexBoy - The rationale is explained ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461734/build-separate-versions-of-api-from-same-project-using-maven